# Internet Connection Fails

Tags: java, android

I'm quite new in the android world and I’m developing an App but I'm not able to establish any internet connection (or even if I try to send a e-mail) both with data connection and wifi. Everything works fine until commands such as (for example):

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setReadTimeout(10000);

conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

conn.setDoInput(true);

conn.connect();    // here it fails
```

OR

```
InetAddress indirizzo = InetAddress.getByName("www.websitename.com"); // here it fails
```

OR

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

ftpClient.connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",21);  // here it fails
```

I have tried a lot of solutions I found in different tutorials: the code works fine on my PC in java applications but the same code doesn’t work on my smartphone nor on AVDs . I have used all the needed permissions in the manifest file:

```
"android.permission.INTERNET"

"android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```

but I think that something is missing. Does anyone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: what the 144.76.105.237 ? Does this ip is inner?

Comment: you are trying with a real / accessible website right?

Comment: It is a ftp site! I have tried also with other ftp but it doesn't work!

Comment: I'm able to access the same site if I try with a java application on my PC, but I can't from my smartphone or AVD :-(

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your device have internet connection or not :-

```
public static boolean CheckInternet(Context context) 
{
    ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    return wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected();
}
```

Read below documentation :-

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html

```
private void downloadImage(String urlStr) {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Fetching Image...");
        final String url = urlStr;

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                InputStream in = null;
                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.what = 1;
                try {
                    in = openHttpConnection(url);
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putParcelable("bitmap", bitmap);
                    msg.setData(b);
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                messageHandler.sendMessage(msg);    

            }
        }.start();

    }
```

Comment: I have checked the connectvity with ConnectivityManager and the device results to be connected with the "mobile connection" !

Comment: @user3730384 it means this function return you true ?

Comment: ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  
NetworkInfo[] info = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
for (int i = 0; i<info.length; i++){if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED){
Log.i("ActivityDemo", "connected to "+info[i].getTypeName());
}
else
Log.i("ActivityDemo", "not connected to "+info[i].getTypeName()); 
}

Comment: I tried the code Golu suggested me and it works fine! After I included my code inside a Thread and it wors as well !! So all I need to do is to use a separated thread for connect functions (ftp or http , etc)! Thanks a lot Golu !!

Comment: @user3730384 now you can achieve your task or what?

Comment: Yes I can achive it! Thanks again!